# Creating editable table which is generated by JSON

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

I have this function which generates a table of some words correctly :

```
function show(json) {
    var content = '<table id = "myTable" border = 1>';
    var counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < json.length; counter++) {
        content += '<tr><td class = "topics">' + json[counter]['topic_name'] + '</td>'
        '</tr>';
    }
    content += '</table>';
    $('#table_here').append(content);
}
```

I want to make this table editable, so that when a user clicks on a cell on a table he should edit that cell. So I wrote this with the help of a tutorial online :

```
function show(json) {
    var content = '<table id = "myTable" border = 1>';
    var counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < json.length; counter++) {
        content += '<tr id =' + counter + ' class="edit_tr"><td class = "edit_td"><span id = "first_' + counter + '" class="text">' + json[counter]['topic_name'] + '</span><input type="text" value="' + json[counter]['topic_name'] + '" class="editbox"  id = "first_input_' + counter + '" /&gt;></td>'
        '</tr>';
    }
    content += '</table>';
    $('#table_here').append(content);
}
```

When I open this page both word in the cells and the word in the box in that cell appear at the same time.And when I click on somewhere on the page the boxes disappear and only words remain, but nothing happens when I click on the words. How can I fix this? 
I get the codes from this tutorial : http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dunno what error you're facing but here's a <kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/m7TYX/)</kbd>. In the demo, I've used an array of colors which look like this :

```
[
 {
  "colorName": "red",
  "hexValue": "#f00"
 },
 {
   "colorName": "green",
   "hexValue": "#0f0"
 },
 .. so on
]
```

You need two click functions :

1. To show the text box when you click on the color:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", ".edit_td", function () {
      //reset to default, hide every input and show span in table
      $("input:text").hide();
      $(".text").show();
      $(this).find("span").hide().end().find("input:text").show();
   });
   ```
2. To hide the textbox and show span when clicked anywhere other than `table`

   ```
   $(document).on("click", function (event) {
     var $target = $(event.target);
     if ($target.closest("table").length == 0) {
       var $input = $("input:text:visible");
       var value = $input.val();
       $input.closest("td").find(".text").text(value).show();
       $input.parent().hide();
     }
   ```

   });

Edit :

Added a `keyup` handler for the input button attached to it:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input:text", function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest("td").find(".text").html(value).show();
    $(this).parent().hide();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Click on the demo on top to see the update :)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for such a nice code. But the value of the cell doesn't change after editing in your code.

Comment: @bahittin do u need a save button next to the textbox or must a blur event save it?

Comment: it needs to be saved after the user hits enter or clicks somewhere else after writing new word on the cell.

Comment: thanks for the button but can we do this without a button? by just clicking enter after writing the new word.

Answer (score 1):

use http://handsontable.com/  a minimalistic Excel-like data grid editor for HTML, JavaScript & jQuery